# Application crawling using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, web-crawler

I am trying to get visit all links present in a website and wanted to check its status (HTTP 200 or 500 etc). I am getting problem in dealing with new window generated after clicking some link. Few links leads to new windows where as few other open in same window. How to check for new window and switch to that and come back to main window. Here Is my code so far:

```
public class TestLink {
    //list to save visited links
    static List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    WebDriver driver;

    public TestLink(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void linkTest() {
        // loop over all the a elements in the page
            try{
            for(WebElement link : driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"))) {
                // Check if link is displayed and not previously visited
                if (link.isDisplayed() 
                            && !links.contains(link.getText())) {
                    // add link to list of links already visited
                    links.add(link.getText());
                    System.out.println(link.getText());
                    // click on the link. This opens a new page
                    link.click();
                    // call testLink on the new page
                    new TestLink(driver).linkTest();
                }
            }
            driver.navigate().back();
        }catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");
        // start recursive linkText
        new TestLink(driver).linkTest();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Below code is working fine for string url, but I want status code for each link in website. How to construct url for each link dynamically.

```
 public static int getResponseCode(String url) {
        try {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
           // webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            if(url != null)
            return client.getPage(url).getWebResponse().getStatusCode();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is Seleniums intended usage and such use should be discouraged. You are much better off using some http library or even command line utilities like cURL or wget together with some parser. Also, webdriver does not provide any information on HTTP status codes. I would ask here - the status code of what? If you load a new page there are usually tens of different resources being downloaded, each of them having their own status code.

That said, if you still want to do it with Selenium, then yes, take all visible links into `List<WebElement>` and send click to them. By default, the new link is opened in new window, so prior to clicking you must know your parent window handle, after clicking wait for new window handles and then switch to it, do whatever you need to do and close the window, starting the next round in loop. Check the docs [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html), you are probably interested in `getWindowHandles()` and `switchTo()`.

For status codes you need to route your traffic thru a proxy. I would use [browsermob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy). It can get the performance data in HAR format, that includes all the requests and responses, including status codes, so you could possibly do something like:

```
Har har = server.getHar();
if (har == null) return;
for (HarEntry entry : har.getLog().getEntries()){
    if ((String.valueOf(entry.getResponse().getStatus()).startsWith("4"))
            || (String.valueOf(entry.getResponse().getStatus()).startsWith("5"))){
          // take action
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Erki M please have a look at my edited question and let me know if you have any idea on that.